# Grails Audit Logging Plugin - Performance

Tags: performance, grails, logging, grails-orm

I'm using [Grails Audit Logging Plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/audit-logging) for logging create/edit/delete operations on my grails app.

Does anyone know whether the actual logging (saving the log to DB) is executed in a separate thread or will the response for a request (that incidentally modifies a few records, say) be returned only after the logging is done. Couldn't find anything on this anywhere in their docs or outside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Hibernate Event System](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/events.html) is used [internally](https://github.com/hartsock/grails-audit-logging-plugin/blob/master/src/groovy/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/plugins/orm/auditable/AuditLogListener.groovy#L41) by this plugin. The messages are processed in a blocking way, therfore the response will be recieved **after** the logging is done.

It's quite easy to reproduce - just create a custom Hibernate listener:

```
import org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.PostInsertEventListener;
import org.hibernate.event.PostUpdateEvent;
import org.hibernate.event.PostUpdateEventListener;

class HibernateDummyListener implements PostInsertEventListener, PostUpdateEventListener {

    public void onPostInsert(final PostInsertEvent event) {
        println "Hibernate: ON POST INSERT"

        //No delay
    }

    public void onPostUpdate(final PostUpdateEvent event) {
        println "Hibernate: ON POST UPDATE"

        Thread.sleep(10000)
    }
}
```

...and resources.groovy:

```
beans = {
   hibernateDummyListener(HibernateDummyListener)

   hibernateEventListeners(HibernateEventListeners) {
      listenerMap = ['post-insert':hibernateDummyListener,
                     'post-update':hibernateDummyListener]
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the analysis and the example. Now this means, I probably need to roll out my own. Since i do not need the exact changes logged, i should be able to roll out something that does not block.

Comment: You're welcome. If I were you, I would consider using log4j for this purpose (AsynchAppender should do the trick). This might save you some time.